# iOS Simulator crashes after xCode 7 and xCode 6.4 installation

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am on Yosemite and I had xCode 6.3 and xCode 7 beta 1. When I updated xCode 6.3 to 6.4 simulator started to crash. I attach the crash log. It seems like xCode 7 overwrote some library that's crashing when 6.4 is trying to use. Any ideas? I'd like to avoid re-imaging my Mac because of this.

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   launchd_sim                     0x0000000109c95fee 0x109c6e000 + 163822
1   launchd_sim                     0x0000000109c72dc4 0x109c6e000 + 19908
2   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000010a07c145 start + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

this is my problem
My mac environment is OSX 10.10 , install Xcode 7.1 and Xcode 6.4 .

Problem : Open xib will crash in Xcode 6.4 and run simulator some image didn't show.

Then this is crash log :

> ProductBuildVersion: 6E35b
>   ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-7703/InterfaceBuilder/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:45
>   Details:  Failed to launch Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder WatchKit Tool." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fda9024eda0 {Error Domain=IBMessageChannelErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to communicate with Interface Builder" UserInfo={IBAbstractPlatformToolCrashLog=
>   Dyld Error Message:
>     Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PepperUICore.framework/PepperUICore
>     Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/Interface Builder WatchKit Tool
>     Reason: image not found

Solution:
i don't know why Xcode 6.4 will use iOS 9.0.simruntime when run simulator,
so i open finder and then go to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes move  iOS 9.0.simruntime out
then Xcode6.4 will be fine.

hope it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo ln -s "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PepperUICore.framework" /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PepperUICore.framework

sudo ln -s "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework" /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SockPuppetGizmo.framework
```

Use this both and you will get solution.